# listening to rabbit queue

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

i am listening to rabbit queue via spring-queue and I am getting this error:

> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Failed to invoke target method 'orchestrate' with argument type = [class [B], value = [{[B@109a1f6c}]
>   at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:408) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.*.*.*.*.method([B)

my method accepts List.

```
@Bean public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory listenerContainer(){
SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new 
SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
factory.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
factory.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
} 
@Bean public MessageListenerAdapter newTest() { 
return new MessageListenerAdapter(testing, "method"); 
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You need to show your `testing.method()`.

Also, the `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` requires the content type header to contain `json`, such as `application/json`.

It also needs some type information in headers so it knows what type to convert to; otherwise you'll just get a `Map`.

Consider using the `@RabbitListener` annotation instead, and upgrade to a newer version of Spring AMQP (the current version is 1.7.3); the type information for the `@RabbitListener` method is conveyed to the converter.